# How to debug a finally block in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

How do I debug the `finally` block in a `try {...} finally{...}` in the event of an uncaught exception? It seems that no matter what I do with the exception settings or debugger, Visual Studio will not let me proceed past the point of the thrown exception in the `try` block in order to debug the `finally` code.

Here's a representative, short example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var instrument = new Instrument();
    try
    {
        instrument.TurnOnInstrument();
        instrument.DoSomethingThatMightThrowAnException();
        throw new Exception(); // Visual Studio won't let me get past here. Only option is to hit "Stop Debugging", which does not proceed through the finally block
    }
    finally
    {
        if(instrument != null)
            instrument.TurnOffInstrument();
    }
}
```

Context: I have a program that controls some hardware instruments used for taking electronic measurements in a lab, e.g. programmable PSUs. In the event that something goes wrong, I want it to fail fast: first shut down the instruments to prevent possible physical damage and then exit. The code to shut them down is in the finally block, but I have no way to debug that this code works in the error case. I don't want to try to handle any possible errors, just turn the instruments and then shut the program down. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: have you put a breakpoint on a line in the `finally` block?

Comment: Could you show us a small example of your code? if you want to catch all exceptions without worrying about them being uncaught then you will need to add a catch block for the `Exception` class.

Comment: As a side note, I do not seriously think that using a PC to e.g. PWM control an H-bridge.
Any exceptions, or just swapping, deadlocks and whatever, and you might stop with both MOSFETs/IGBTs open.
This might or might not be like your usage case, of course.

Comment: @hometoast yes, that doesn't help

Comment: @Victor Thanks, but not seeking comments on the overall application. This is not a real-time application with timing sensitive issues like that, I'm using Nation Instruments PXI hardware and they supply the .NET drivers to control it programmatically, so I don't think I'm doing anything too crazy.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finally block is never executed if the exception results in a crash of the application, that is the case in your code.
To debug the finally block in your exemple, you have to put the whole code of your main function in an other try statement, and catch the exception to prevent the application to crash, like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var instrument = new Instrument();
        try
        {
            instrument.TurnOnInstrument();
            instrument.DoSomethingThatMightThrowAnException();
            throw new Exception();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (instrument != null)
                instrument.TurnOffInstrument();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         Console.Writeline("An exception occured");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can set breakpoint ( F9 key ) and Alt + Ctrl + B Keys to see the list of breakpoints.
2. You can break in between using IntelliTrace, As :

   [image: Set IntelliTrace Settings]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps, however Visual Studio 2015 Pro SKU does not have Intellitrace, which shouldn't be necessary for this anyways. Also, I know how to set/view breakpoints. Even when single-stepping, code execution won't advance past the exception throw, so setting a breakpoint doesn't help if the code never gets there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a breakpoint on the first line *inside* the `finally` block, then click "Run" again after the exception.

Comment: That doesn't work, when the exception is thrown I get "Exception was unhandled. An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception occured in "Blah.exe"". Clicking run just repeats this.

Comment: Of course, the breakpoint will never fire in your example if the instrument is null.
I'd add some static unconditional code for testing the breakpoint.

Comment: It's just an example, and the breakpoint will hit if I put it on the `if` block itself. However execution never advances to the finally block, so it's a moot point.